# how to install old versions of FreeBSD? (FreeBSD 12.2p4)

Tags: freebsd

I'm trying to reproduce an issue in some code that occurs on OpenSSL 1.1.1K on FreeBSD 12.2p4.

I downloaded and installed [FreeBSD-12.2-RELEASE-amd64-dvd1.iso](https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/releases/ISO-IMAGES/12.2/FreeBSD-12.2-RELEASE-amd64-dvd1.iso), which installed FreeBSD 12.2-RELEASE-p9 with OpenSSL 1.1.1h-freebsd but that didn't reproduce the problem.

(I'm trying to reproduce https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/26425#issuecomment-814034012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that release folder I'm only seeing the latest release in each branch. If you look under snapshots there are some older ISOs you can try:

https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/snapshots/amd64/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/12.2/

I see one that is a month old.

If the issue is with an old version of OpenSSL it might be easier to install an older version of that one package rather than try to roll back an entire OS just to get the right version of a package.

Use `/usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portdowngrade` to find old versions of any package found in ports, which [OpenSSL 1.1.1h](https://www.freshports.org/security/openssl/) is certainly in there.

EXAMPLE:

```
portdowngrade security/openssl r551541
```